# how to generate po file from js file using poedit

Tags: javascript, localization, gettext, poedit

i am using **Gettext.js** library to localize my contents generated from a JS file. Now the situation is, i have to create and write each and every po files manually. I know we can scan php files for gettext strings using PoEdit. So, is it possible to scan JS files for gettext strings using **PoEdit**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Achieved this by creating a new parser of python language in PoEdit.

File > Preferences > Parsers > New

Language:

```
JS
```

List of extension:

```
*.js
```

Parser command:

```
xgettext --language=Python --force-po -o %o %C %K %F
```

Item in Keyword List:

```
-k%k
```

Item in input files list:

```
%f
```

Source code charset:

```
--from-code=%c
```

i found this tutorial while searching on this, which helped me to attain the situation [Tutorial Here>>](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.telesphore.org/2009/02/27/poedit-xgettext-et-javascript/&prev=/search?q=poedit%2bjavascript&client=firefox-a&hs=vMU&hl=en&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&biw=1440&bih=772)

Actually the tutorial is in French and the link is a google translated(to English) one.

Comment: This worked for me when I changed `--language=Python` to `--language=C`

Answer (score 5):

Since version **xgettext 0.18.3**, you can use [JavaScript as the language parameter](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7641).

This version of xgettext is used in Poedit since at least version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

`xgettext` now supports JavaScript natively, so the command is simply:

```
xgettext --output=output.pot --language=JavaScript *.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) commandline program is used to scan source code and can parse the following languages:

C, C++, ObjectiveC, Shell, Python, Lisp, EmacsLisp, librep, Scheme, Java, C#, awk, Tcl, Perl, PHP, GCC-source, Glade

Although JavaScript is not listed as a language, I just tried it with a few and Perl actually worked. Try this:

```
echo " testFunc('foo');" > test.js;
xgettext --keyword=testFunc --output=- test.js --language="perl";
```

To do this from POEdit, open `Preferences > Parsers > Perl` add `;*.js` to the file extensions list and add `--language=Perl` after `xgettext` in the Parser command field. This worked for me and I was able to get new strings from a JS file this way.

Although I don't know how gettext.js works a better approach may be to [convert PO files to a native JavaScript file format](http://localise.biz/free/converter/po-to-json).